# Autowiring two different objects to a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC and trying to add fields in existing form validate them.  once the validation is complete, I need to map the data entered in form to a different object.
The configuration of the spring bean is something like below.

```
<bean id="SampleController"
    class="com.abcd.controller.SampleController"
    parent="AbstractxyzMlsController">
    <property name="formView"            value="abc/my_view" />
    <property name="highLightedTab"      value="DataRequirement" />
    <property name="commandName"         value="dataRequirement" />
    <property name="commandClass"        value="com.abcd.dataRequirementResponse" />
    <property name="validator"                            ref="DataAcceptanceValidator" />
</bean>
```

From the form of above spring bean configuration, I need to modify it accept few more fields and put them under a different object. I cannot use the same object as in the commandclass mentioned above. And i also need to validate the fields i add in the form. I see that the current validator accepts the object DataRequirement alone.

Do i need to come up with a different validator? Also How do i add the second object where I am going to put the fields in?

Sorry if the question was dumb. Just trying to understand and implement.

Answer (score 1):

*It is impossible to have multiple objects for same form.*

> But there is the way, you can use multiple objects like this :

**Backend** :

```
public class FormObject() {
    Class1 class1Object;
    Class2 class2Object;
    //Getter and setter
}
```

**Frontend** :

```
<form:form
  action="../someAction"
  method="post" commandName="formObject">

  ...
  <form:input type="text" path="class1Object.property"/>
  ...
  <form:input type="text" path="class2Object.property"/>
  ...
</form:form>
```

Comment: How do i specify my spring configuration for the new FormObject class?

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called jsr303 and hibernate validator. with help of Binding results we can get all the error messages.
Refer the following link.

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api